# How to extract latest commit hash for a remote git repository in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, command-line

I am trying to read the latest commit for a git remote repository using this command

```
git ls-remote https://repo.myrepository.com/scm/swc/project.git refs/heads/qa
```

it works fine and returns me something like this

```
5261626431661281d788382a1ed6ab1440fd93a8        refs/heads/qa
```

But I am not able to find online any way to extract only the commit hash from the returned string in command line

I thought it would be very easy to find this information online, but the only answer I am finding everywhere is this

```
git ls-remote https://repo.myrepository.com/scm/swc/project.git refs/heads/qa | \ cut -f 1
```

But this does not work in windows command line, it says `cut` is not a recognized command.

Can anybody please help for windows command line version of it?

Comment: What operating system do you use? `cut` is a linux command.

Comment: @dan1st - Windows

Comment: This was closed as needs clarity, but to be fair the problem is clear and it was already tagged with `cmd`.

Comment: @jnovack question is open for answers now.

Answer (score 1):

`for /f` is how you get can "cut" tokens with a delimiter.

In the following examples, the `delims` is a <kbd>Space</kbd>.

```
# inside of a batch file
# get first token, delimited by <space>
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in (
    'git ls-remote https://repo.myrepository.com/scm/swc/project.git refs/heads/qa'
) do echo %%a
```

```
# command line
# get second token, delimited by <space>
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %a in ('echo one two') do echo %a
```

[image]